# SQL Count (*) doesn't display the correct data

Tags: sql

Hello I have got the problem with my query and it display the correct data but not correct amount (count (*)). Somehow it should display the data as 1 for that part but it display 4.
I don't know where is the error is.

```
select Vehical_Type, 
       Vehical_Registration_No, 
       count(*) 
from van, 
     van_booking 
where Vehical_Type = 'Ford - Transit' 
  and Vehical_Registration_No <> fk2_Vehical_Registration_No 
         not in (select fk2_Vehical_Registration_No 
                 from van_booking 
                 where '2010.10.12' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date 
                    or '2010.10.11' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date);
```

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: That SQL is invalid: *Vehical_Registration_No <> fk2_Vehical_Registration_No not in (...)* will definitely throw an error. Additionally you are using an aggregate function without a `GROUP BY` which is illegal in nearly every DBMS except MySQL - which might produce inconsistent results. See this link for details: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: You should not use the "old, legacy-style" JOIN like this `from van, van_booking` - instead, "upgrade" your mind to the explicit JOIN syntaxes as defined in the ANSI SQL standard: `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN` and so forth. They're the standard, they're much clearer to read and understand - only benefits!

Comment: @Kumu, I agree with @Sarfraz, if you don't accept people's answers, then they will not have enough motive to answer your questions. This is how StackOverflow work. You help people and expect points in return (votes & accept). I respect someone who help without expecting something in return, but that's unfortunately rare!

Comment: Thank you for all you answers and I would like to use the joins

Comment: @Promather - I appreciate all your comments and help I didn't check this out and that's why I didn't reply and let me try this first then I will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do we start?

```
select Vehical_Type, Vehical_Registration_No, count(*)
from van, van_booking
where Vehical_Type = 'Ford - Transit'
  and Vehical_Registration_No <> fk2_Vehical_Registration_No
**not in (**
  select fk2_Vehical_Registration_No
  from van_booking
  where '2010.10.12' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date
     or '2010.10.11' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date);
```

Since there is no "AND " before the NOT IN, so

1. there is no context as to whether it should be right or wrong
2. the query won't even run

At least try to post a working query since you seem to indicate it works (and returns count=>4).

Secondly, please alias the table names so that you can prefix the columns with the alias names. At present, it is ambiguous as to which columns belong to which tables.

Thirdly, I guess this is MySQL? You should always state which DBMS you are working with, but MySQL is the only one that will let you get away with **MIXING** aggregate and non-aggregate fields **WITHOUT** a GROUP BY clause.

Fourthly, please try to learn to use SQL92 ANSI joins instead of the old-style cross-join and filter-in-WHERE.  It looks like you have crossed Van and Van_Booking tables without any correlation clause.  What are you trying to achieve?

Lastly, and this ties to the last point, it would greatly help to list out some sample data rows and what the result should look like based on that sample data.

I am going to guess that what you are actually after is a list of vehicle registration numbers of the type requested, but at the same time, in the COUNT column, show... the total number of records matching the query? So, something like this?

```
Type | Registration | Count
Ford - Transit | ABC123 | 4
Ford - Transit | D4 | 4
Ford - Transit | XY13 | 4
Ford - Transit | PQS333 | 4
```

It's just a guess, but without the count, you can use this

```
select Vehical_Type, Vehical_Registration_No
from van
where Vehical_Type = 'Ford - Transit'
  and Vehical_Registration_No not in (
  select fk2_Vehical_Registration_No
  from van_booking
  where '2010.10.12' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date
     or '2010.10.11' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date);
```

To include the count (which would be the same value in all rows), you can duplicate the query as a subquery to itself

```
select Vehical_Type, Vehical_Registration_No, C.C
from van
cross join (
    select COUNT(*) C
    from van
    where Vehical_Type = 'Ford - Transit'
      and Vehical_Registration_No not in (
      select fk2_Vehical_Registration_No
      from van_booking
      where '2010.10.12' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date
         or '2010.10.11' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date)) C
where Vehical_Type = 'Ford - Transit'
  and Vehical_Registration_No not in (
  select fk2_Vehical_Registration_No
  from van_booking
  where '2010.10.12' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date
     or '2010.10.11' between Hire_Start_Date and Hire_End_Date);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I tried to use your query and it worked.I would like your suggestions and I will try to do them all.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `count (*)` will display count including `NULLS` where as `count(fieledName)` will display count **without** `NULLS`. You should go with appropriate option.

Comment: It is a straight inner join and there does not seem to be a any field that is counted specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your DBMS allows the absence of the `GROUP BY` and the invalid expression with the NOT IN is just a copy & paste error, I'd say your problem is the missing join.

You don't join `van` to `van_booking` so the statement generates a cartesian product of those tables. Meaning **every** row from `van` is joined to **every** row from `van_booking` which is most probably not what you want.

I guess you will want something like:

```
FROM van
  JOIN van_booking ON van.id = van_booking.van_id
```

To properly join those two tables.

Comment: +1 for using the proper ANSI SQL-92 JOIN syntax ! That's the way it ought to be always...

Comment: Thank you for your help and I tried to use the following query.
Then its working and I will learn about the joins and try to use them.Then I can get rid of the Cartesian Products.